# how can i change value of parameters in a axio fetch fuction

Tags: javascript, typescript, ajax, axios

I have the follow axios code fetch data like this , but cannot work.

```
getdata(par:any){
        axios.get(url)
            .then(response => par.sqltxt=this.trans.transray(response.data))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    console.log(par);        
    // return par;
    };
```

and other code like

```
const  para = {s01:'01',sqltxt:'insert into '};
server.get('/api',(req:Request,resp:Response,next:NextFunction) =>{    
    resp.send('hello api ');
    gaxios.getdata(para); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`axios.get` returns a `Promise`, which is asynchronous.  Which means that your `console.log(par)` is executed before the result is returned from the api.  There are a few approaches you can take here.

1. Run your work inside a `.then()`.

```js
getdata(par:any){
    axios.get(url)
        .then(response => par.sqltxt=this.trans.transray(response.data))
        .then(result => {
            // run your work here, but you can not return it
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

You can also just return the `axios.get` but then your `getdata(par:any)` returns a Promise, which you need to call `then` on.

```
getdata(par:any){
    return axios.get(url)
        .then(response => par.sqltxt=this.trans.transray(response.data))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};    
getdata({}).then(result => {
    // run your work here,
});
```

2. Make your function use async/await

```js
async getdata(par:any){
    const result = await axios.get(url)
         .then(response => par.sqltxt=this.trans.transray(response.data))
         .catch((error) => console.log(error));
     
    // run your work here, you can return it.  
};
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but choose the best method for your use-case

Comment: ur  anwser are so  clear and helpful , i learned asynchronous isnt realtime .thanks